# I want to clear contents of file in chrome extension and the file is on server. How to do that?

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome

I have written the below code in my js file in chrome extension.

```
var xhr_put = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr_put.open('PUT',"https://something/index.php",true);

xhr_put.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    console.log('File Cleared',"Yes");
}
```

And the below code in my PHP file.

```
$requestmethod = 'PUT';
if ($_REQUEST['REQUEST_METHOD'] === $requestmethod)
{
    $f = @fopen("facebookmsg.txt", "w");
     print "in here";
    if ($f !== false) {
    ftruncate($f, 0);
    fclose($f);
    echo "here";
    }
}
```

But my file on server is not getting empty. I need help as to what is wrong and how do i correct it?

Comment: `xhr_put.onreadystatechange` you aren't using onreadystatechange correctly -  just because that callback is called does not mean you have made a successful request - not that it would ever be called, because you aren't even making a request with that code - [see documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: You never call `xhr_put.send()`. You need to call `send()` to actually send the request.

Comment: Thanks. I have added send method and can see request reaching server. But it is not processing my code for PUT request.